# Hyphen cutting off string when using subject.left

Tags: apex, class

Firstly, apologies, I'm not a developer! We have a piece of code that reads as follows

```
 String ref = ' (Ref:IN:' + incident.Name + ')';
                  subject = subject.left(235) + ref;
```

When we try to send an email from within the Remedyforce console it should populate the subject line like so "This is a test subject Ref:IN:00125455"

However if the subject has a hypen, it will not pull through any of the subject before the hyphen.

For example if my subject is "This is a test subject" - This really is a test subject it will pull through "This really is a test subject Ref:IN:012546"

Any ideas on how we can prevent it chopping anything off to the left of the hyphen?

Comment: Why are you using left(235)? That should get the leftmost 235 characters. How is subject getting set originally? This code shouldn't cut anything off at the hyphen. Is there a line of code somewhere like subject.split('-')[1]?

Comment: This code should not cut off left of hyphen, there should be something else on the code which does it.